# Nested request in Eloquent using first request as where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Model named Campaign which belongs to 2 other models 'Client' and 'Coupon'.

Now based on a campaignId I need to find the campaign with this Id, but also the other campaigns with the same clientId.

I was able to do it with 2 requests and merging the results but I'm pretty sure it can be done in a single request.

Just in case here are my 2 requests :

```
$couponDetails = Campaign::with(['coupon', 'client'])
                    ->where('uuid', '=', $campaignId)
                    ->get()
                    ->all();

$extraCoupon = Campaign::with(['coupon', 'client'])
                    ->where('client_id', '=', $couponDetails[0]->client_id)
                    ->whereNotIn('uuid', [$couponDetails[0]->uuid])
                    ->get()
                    ->all();
```

I guess I should be doing a nested select on the campaignId and then a where clause on the clientId received but I can't find the correct syntax.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: ***the other campaigns with the same clientId*** not equals `$couponDetails[0]->client_id`. Either edit your question or edit your code.

Comment: You are getting a collection of `Campaign`s, but `client_id` belongs to only first one.

Comment: @Tarasovych Sorry I'm not sure to understand what you mean. Every campaign has a client_id, I just want to retrieve all the campaigns with the same client_id as the campaign with the uuid sent.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for `orWhere` in laravel which will give you something like this:

```
$coupons = Campaign::with(['coupon', 'client'])
    ->where(function($query) use ($campaignId){
        $query->where('uuid', '=', $campaignId);
    })
    ->orWhere(function($query) use ($couponDetails){
        $query->where('client_id', '=', $couponDetails[0]->client_id)
              ->whereNotIn('uuid', [$couponDetails[0]->uuid]);
    })
    ->get()
    ->all();
```

Comment: This don't fix my problem since I still need to make 2 request, the first one that will let me retrieve the clientId associated with my campaignId.